# On clicking Highlight background of div in master page

Tags: javascript, html, css

The master page have some link.The static part has a list of anchor.onclick the content part is change.
How to make a highlight to the click anchor tag?

e.g

master page content

HOME   PROFILE  MASSEGES

---

content part here

---

I want to change the background when I clicking perticular anchor tag. on the static view.

Suppose this is the code in masetr page. static code for all pages.

```
<div id="menu"> 
<ul> 
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" >Profile</a></li> 
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" >Messeges</a></li> </ul> 
</div>
```

I want to clicking on particular event, the background of that anchor has to change.

Comment: As it stands, the question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? Do you have any code with you to show ... `:/`

Comment: @PraveenKumar pls check edited part

Comment: @PraveenKumar got it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this.

```
$("#yourTagId").click(function(){
    $("#yourTagId").css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

In your case you should give al li tags an unique ID